# Taking from a file then summing the integers but getting 0 as answer

Tags: java, file, sum

Hey guys i have a problem. I'm trying to sum the integers from a file using `hasNextInt()` but i'm getting 0 as the sum. I can't find my mistake please help me.

Here's the codes:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Number4 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner square = null;

    try
    {
        square = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("Squares.txt"));
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.out.print("File not found");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    String num1,num2,num3,num4,num5,num6,num7,num8,num9,num10,num11,num12,num13,num14,num15,num16,num17,num18,num19,num20;

    num1 = square.next();
    num2 = square.next();
    num3 = square.next();
    num4 = square.next();
    num5 = square.next();
    num6 = square.next();
    num7 = square.next();
    num8 = square.next();
    num9 = square.next();
    num10 = square.next();
    num11 = square.next();
    num12 = square.next();
    num13 = square.next();
    num14 = square.next();
    num15 = square.next();
    num16 = square.next();
    num17 = square.next();
    num18 = square.next();
    num19 = square.next();
    num20 = square.next();

    System.out.println(""+num1+"\n"+num2+"\n"+num3+"\n"+num4+"\n"+num5+"\n"+num6+"\n"+num7+"\n"+num8+"\n"+num9+"\n"+num10+num11+"\n"+num12+"\n"+num13+"\n"+num14+"\n"+num15+"\n"+num16+"\n"+num17+"\n"+num18+"\n"+num19+"\n"+num20);


    int next,sum = 0;

    while(square.hasNextInt())
    {
        next = square.nextInt();
        sum = next + sum; 
    }


    System.out.print("The sum is "+sum);
    square.close();

}

}
```

Comment: could you provide Squares.txt file?May be you already call square.next() 20 times.

Comment: You read all the numbers before the summation !!! that means no numbers to summ left

Comment: The Squares.txt file only contains the squares of the number from 1-10 in the format 1 1 2 4 3 9 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your this subset of code is doing the same thing. why to create too many variables. simply iterate over all the integers in file, show and sum it.

```
 int next,sum = 0;

while(square.hasNextInt())
{
    next = square.nextInt();
    System.out.println(next+"\n");
    sum = next + sum; 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

using square.next() you already read the whole file by the time you are doing  square.nextInt(). reopen the file or write num* at the same time you iterate

Comment: Oh i'm new to files. Is there an appropriate way to do it? But using hasNextInt().

Comment: quick fix just remove all num* = square.next();

Comment: I did and it works but what if i want to display the values from the file first? And then sum it.

Comment: your code is having that part. i answered below, you just need to add one println() in between.

Comment: reading a file twice, once just for logging doesn't really make sense; If you really need to do it twice add it in a list and iterate twice; or another quick hack after  System.out.println(""+num1+"\n"+num2+"\n... just do again square = new Scanner(new FileInputStream("Squares.txt"));

Comment: Okay i'll do it. It's actually simpler than i thought lol. I tried it Prashant, and it works thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If there's 20 numbers in your file, when your code reaches:

```
next = square.nextInt();
```

sees nothing, because you already read the whole file in `num# = square.next();` lines.
(Also note that you can print numbers in file much simpler than what you already did. also if you want, you can calculate the sum of numbers in this loop too. something like this:

```
int sum = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < 20 && square.hasNextInt(); ++i) {
    int num = square.nextInt();
    sum += num;
    System.out.println(num);
}
System.out.print("The sum is " + sum);
square.close();
```